# How to map generic directory requests to the corresponding index.html file in Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a static site in App Engine using the default app.yaml file. The main url handler looks like this:

```
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

I'd like to direct all requests of the forms:

`http://mysite/somedirectory` and `http://mysite/somedirectory/`

to `http://mysite/somedirectory/index.html`

What's a good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For the `http://mysite/somedirectory/` url pattern you could have a handler like this:

```
- url: /(.*)/$
  static_files: www/\1/index.html
  upload: www/.*/index.html
```

Of course, this handler must be inserted before the catch-all handler which you already have.

But for the `http://mysite/somedirectory` url pattern things are tricky, since you can't tell if `somedirectory` represents a file and should be served as-is or a directory, in which case the corresponding `index.html` should be served.

Unless you follow a strict rule which can be used to differentiate files from directories. For example if you know that *all* your files have a `.` in their names and a filename extension following it and *all* directories have no `.` in their names, then you could use a pair of handlers like this:

```
# a "." in name means a file, serve as-is:
- url: /(.*\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]*)$
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/.*

# no "." in name means a directory, serve corresponding index.html:
- url: /((.*))$
  static_files: www/\1/index.html
  upload: www/.*/index.html
```

Since this pair becomes itself a catch-all filter, it should be placed last (all other handlers you may have should be placed before it), replacing the catch-all handler you have.

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Dan's answer put me on the right track. I'll put what I ended up with as a new answer - StackExchange thinks it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Dan's answer put me on the right track. It worked for everything except the root directory. This is what I ended up using:

```
# Ending with a "." followed by non-slashes means a file, serve as-is:
- url: /((.*\.[^\/]+))$
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/.*

# Ending in a slash means a directory, serve corresponding index.html:
- url: /((.*))/$
  static_files: www/\1/index.html
  upload: www/.*/index.html

# Did not match above so must be a directory, serve corresponding index.html:
- url: /((.*))$
  static_files: www/\1/index.html
  upload: www/.*/index.html
```

You can see the site in action at https://www.tameware.com

Comment: Doh! This does not work for all cases - I did not test adequately before posting. I'll work on a fix.

Comment: Fixed and edited. I had used single parens instead of double parens in one of the regexes.

Comment: There's still a problem. All three of these will bring up the same page, as I wanted:

http://mysite/somedirectory
http://mysite/somedirectory/
http://mysite/somedirectory.index.html

But if I navigate using the first link then clicking to access links directly within that directory will not work, giving a 404. Accessing directories within the directory does work - curious!

Comment: If I navigate to the page using the first link then when I try to click on the link for a file within that directory the server looks for it in the site's root directory, that is, in mysite/ instead of in mysite/somedirectory/